# I have a time value which is in 12 hrs format(hh:mm:ss a). Now I want to localize value of "a"(AM/PM) in given language

Tags: java, localization

Time value in English is 02:34:23 AM.

Now, how to get localized time value in español (México) i.e., in "es-mx" with AM value also localized using java.

I tried using `SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(int style, Locale aLocale)`. But only the time value is getting localized and AM/PM is still in English.

Note: Localized value should also be in "hh:mm:ss a" format.

Can someone help me please..

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what are you expecting there instead of AM/PM. Please take look at - http://www.localeplanet.com/java/es-MX/index.html

Comment: @Ismail Actually in angular(Angular 7), localized time value is 02:34:23 a. m. So, to validate that value i'm using java code to which i'm passing the language and time value(in English) and I was expecting the AM to be a. m. after localization. But as per the link you have mentioned, this in not possible using java. So, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to format dates/times for a conversion you have to parse the input and that requires two `DateFormat` objects. One is for setting the input and another to parse the input. To understand how I formatted `String input` using `"HH:mm:ss"` and `KK:mm a` refer to Date and Times Patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number"here").

You mentioned you wanted it specifically formatted for Mexico. AM/PM time format in Mexico is the same as in `en`, they use the 12-hour time format. However if you are looking to have it formatted like `a. m.` simply change `es_MX` to `es`. More info on that [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/mexico-standards-code-snippets.html).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
       String input = "02:34:23";
       DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
       DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'Time:' KK:mm a", Locale.forLanguageTag("es_MX"));
       System.out.println(outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(input)));
    }
```

Output when using `es` instead of `es_MX`:

```
Time: 02:34 a. m.
```

Comment: i tried above code snippet, but still i'm seeing AM/PM value in the result.

Comment: Use es for Locale.forLanguageTag("es") @Priya

Answer (score 0):

LocalePlanet explains shows AM/PM format for es_MX is same.
http://www.localeplanet.com/java/es-MX/index.html

Still need to change one possible way to write a wrapper method to replace AM/PM with required string.

```
public static String dateConverter(Date date) {
   Locale locale = new Locale("es", "MX");
   DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale);
   String newDate = dateFormat.format(date).replaceAll("AM","myAM").replaceAll("PM","myPM");
   return newDate
}
```